# Illegal initializer for 'java.lang.String' error while supplying tags as cucumber options in my runner class

Tags: cucumber, testng, bdd, cucumber-java

I'm getting compilation error- Illegal initializer for 'java.lang.String' while supplying tags as cucumber options in my runner class. This used to work well with info.cukes, but not working after upgrading to io.cucumber.

Here is my runner class-

```
import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;

@CucumberOptions(
        features = "target/test-classes",
        monochrome = true,
        plugin ={"json:target/cucumber-report.json", "html:target/cucumber-reports.html"},
        tags = {"@Smoke", "@Sanity","@Reg"} )

public abstract class BaseRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
}
```

attaching same below-
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace with `tags="@Smoke or @Sanity or @Reg"`, or `tags="@Smoke and @Sanity and @Reg"`, whichever you want.

Answer (score -1):

In io.cucumber the tags should be written without the '{}'
So it becomes,

```
@CucumberOptions(
    features = "target/test-classes",
    monochrome = true,
    plugin ={"json:target/cucumber-report.json", "html:target/cucumber-reports.html"},
    tags = "@Smoke", "@Sanity","@Reg" )
```

And it should work.

Comment: This is just plain wrong, and the answer should be removed.